# How to make a select option change options in another select

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have two drop down. SelCurrentManuf and selCurrentModel. I want the option in selCurrentModel to change depending on the option selected in selCurrentManuf. How do i do it?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selCurrentManuf"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selCurrentModel"></asp:DropDownList>
```

This is how i am currently populating selCurrentModel

```
Public Sub PopulateCurrentModel()
        Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Model where ManufID = "+ selCurrentManuf.Text+";"
        Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(Session("localConn"))
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)

        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

        While myReader.Read
            Dim newListItem As New ListItem
            newListItem.Value = myReader.GetString("Modelid")
            newListItem.Text = myReader.GetString("desc")
            selCurrentModel.Items.Add(newListItem)
        End While

        myReader.Close()
        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub
```

but it only populates the first selected manuf, and doesnt change after

```
Private Sub selCurrentManuf_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles selCurrentManuf.SelectedIndexChanged

       PopulateCurrentModel()
End Sub
```

Comment: this question does not have anything to do with .net, ajax, vb.net, vb, asp etc, it concerns solely javascript.

Comment: is [this example](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/) what you intend to do? or [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/03/06/asp-net-mvc-cascading-dropdown-lists-tutorial-part-1-defining-the-problem-and-the-context.aspx)?

Comment: ah yes thats what i am trying to do, but the xample is in c#  i think i am usin vb

Comment: @Uku This sounds like the kind of problem that I'd use AJAX to solve, personally.

Comment: I was thinking that also any idea how i could refresh the selCurrentModel drop down when selCurrentMauf is selected?

Comment: Obligatory comment about SQL injection issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all that was needed! autopostback="true" !!

Answer (score 0):

Change `selCurrentManuf.Text` to `selCurrentManuf.SelectedItem.Value`

PLEASE NOTE:  You have a SQL Injection security vulnerability.  Please search on SQL Injection and fix.

Comment: Your existing code had `selCurrentManuf`, without more code I can't say why you get this error.  Typo?  Did you change something else?

Comment: Sorry i tried it on a different page. but even with it on the page i showed when a user drops the box down and changes the model the other drop down's values does not change, it doesnt run the function again

Comment: Are you hooked into the on change event?  The on change event should call the code above.

Comment: Doesnt work with my on change, does my on change look correct?

Comment: Add a `selCurrentModel.Items.Clear()` before the loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4031/discussion-between-beginner-and-hogan)